# nested scenario outlines in Behat?

Tags: behat, gherkin

Is it possible to have nested scenario outlines in Behat (Gherkin)

e.g. do all of the below for a different set of Examples

```
 Scenario Outline: Some Outline
   Given step one with <var1>
  When step two with <var2>
   Then step three

Examples:
   | var1 | var2 |
   | 1    | 4    |
   | 2    | 5    |
   | 3    | 6    |
```

Comment: Absolutely, but you should probably quote the placeholders, ie `"<var1>"`

Comment: @AdamElsodaney Could you please provide an example as an answer?

Comment: There's no need to quote the variables.

Answer (score 1):

It's not entirely clear what you mean. The scenario outline you wrote looks fine. It will end up doing the following:

```
Given step one with 1
When step two with 4
Then step three

Given step one with 2
When step two with 5
Then step three

Given step one with 3
Then step two with 6
Then step three
```

But it sounds like perhaps you want to do more like this:

```
Given step one with 1
And step one with 2
And step one with 3
Then step two with 4
And step two with 5
And step two with 6
Then step three
```

This is where [inline tables](http://docs.behat.org/en/latest/guides/1.gherkin.html#tables) come into play. You would do:

```
Scenario: Some Scenario
Given step one
  | var |
  | 1   |
  | 2   |
  | 3   |
When step two
  | var |
  | 4   |
  | 5   |
  | 6   |
Then step three
```

You will need to write the "step one" and "step two" steps in the context file to accept a single `TableNode` argument and iterate over it with `foreach(){}`.